# Is there a way to add separators to sidebar?

Tags: finder, macos, sidebar

I have many locations in my finder sidebar:

[image]

It has became messy, so I would like to add a separator between locations. Is that possibile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There used to be a way to do it cleanly in earlier version of the OS but it is no longer supported.

I use a folder called "---------" which leaves a folder icon at the left edge.

Patrick Welker details a way of doing the same but not having the folder icon by replacing the Smart Folder icon with a transparent one( http://rocketink.net/2013/04/vanilla-finder.html) but that means any Smart Folders are iconless.

Comment: Right. And, I added an update since this (finally) changed for the better in OS X 10.10 (Yosemite). See: http://rocketink.net/2014/07/yosemite-finder-sidebar-separators.html